# C++ : How to calculate modulo of a number raised to large power?

Tags: c++, algorithm, number-theory, modulo

I am solving a programming problem where I have to print the answer in the format answer mod 10 ^ 9 + 7, where 'answer' is the actual answer to the problem.

I have figured out the algorithm to solve the problem, however the caveat is that the answer to the problem is always of the format m * 10 ^ n, where

1 <= m <= 8 and 2 <= n <= 10 ^ 18, that is in the answer 10 can be raised to a power as large as 10 ^ 18. Ofcourse, directly calculating 10 ^ n may overflow.

What should I do next?

Comment: You'll find some methods here: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_algorithm (which, if you're at school, could well be what the professor is aiming towards).

Comment: 2 <= n <= 10 ^ 18? So m * 10 ^ n <= m * 10 ^ (10 ^ 18)?

Comment: A good starting point might be the fact `(x * y) mod n == ((x mod n) * (y mod n)) mod n`

Comment: User @chux has an awesome function written in `C` that does this with a high degree of precision. It is found here : [Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187257/110790).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Evaluating `10^n mod M`:

What you need is [Modular Exponentiation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/fast-modular-exponentiation). It can compute `(a^b)%m` in `log_2(b)`(log base 2).

**Example**

Let's say you need to compute `10^9`.

1. One way is you sequentially multiple `10`, `9` times.
2. Or, use divide and conquer approach.

   `10^9 = (10^8)*(10^1)`

   `10^8 = (10^4)*(10^4)` : Do you need to compute `10^4` twice?

   `10^4 = (10^2)*(10^2)` : Do you need to compute `10^2` twice?

   `10^2 = (10^1)*(10^1)`

   `10^1 = (10^1)*(10^0)`

   `10^0` is the base case.

   So, what we basically do is:

   1. If `power` is an odd number, then we compute `base^(power-1)` and multiply it with `base` to get `base^power`. [`base^power = (base^(power-1)) * base)`]
   2. If `power` is an even number, then we compute `base^(power/2)` and multiply it with itself to get `base^power`. [`base^power = (base^(power/2)) * (base^(power/2))`]. But we compute `base^(power/2)` only once.

**Computational Complexity**:

As stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Computational_complexity):

> A brief analysis shows that such an algorithm uses `floor(log_2(n))`  squarings and
>   at most `floor(log_2(n))`  multiplications. More precisely, the
>   number of multiplications is one less than the number of ones present
>   in the binary expansion of n.

So, we can say that the runtime is of the order of `log_2(n)`. (`O(log_2(power))`)

#### Evaluating the modulo part:

It is easy to notice that while computing a value as large as `10^(10^18)`, we are bound to overflow even largest of the primitive types (`long long int`). And here enters the [Modular Multiplication](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/modular-multiplication), according to which `(a * b) % c = ((a % c) * (b % c)) % c`. As a side note, you might not see this rule in use when you directly look at code, but it is being used if you evalute the recursive calls.

**Problem solved?**

We prevent overflow by computing the modulo on the run. Say, if we got some value as `10^9` and we need to multiply it with itself. Overflow? Nah, not this time.

```
ans = ((10^9 % 1000000007) * (10^9 % 1000000007)) % 1000000007
ans = 10^18 % 1000000007
ans = 49
```

#### Code:

While there are multiple implementations, here is a simple one:

```
const int M = 1e9 + 7;
long long int powxy(long long int x, long long int y) {
    if (y == 0) return 1;
    if (y%2 == 1) return (x*powxy(x, y-1))%M;
    long long int t = powxy(x, y/2);
    return (t*t)%M;
}
```

Tested [here](https://ideone.com/8h8wmh).

Comment: That is beyond awesome. Thanks a tonne :)
PS : I got full marks for the problem.